# Getting Snapshot export failed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am getting the below error while exporting a snapshot in hbase. I have searched the jar in that location. It was there. Also I tried to modify the permissions of the jar after this but it didn't work too.

```
Snapshot export failed!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://master1c.abc.def.com:8020/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.0.2.1.7.0-784-hadoop2.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.runCopyJob(ExportSnapshot.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.run(ExportSnapshot.java:646)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.innerMain(ExportSnapshot.java:697)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot.main(ExportSnapshot.java:701)
```

Answer (score 1):

i faced the similar problem, what you can try doing is if you have bundled your core-site.xml in your code remove it. Bundle only hdfs-site.xml and hbase-site.xml.

the probable cause it FS.defaultfs is set to "hdfs:// .." so it tries to work in that directory.